# Too many records, WAMP gets hang, for exporting my customers with no orders to CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, export

I am trying to export my records for Customers who have not ordered yet, to CSV and while running that script, my local WAMP server gets hault, and no response from my computer, even waiting for an hour.

Total customer records are 23,000 to compare with my total order records of 18,000.

do you guys have any idea, how can i easily export to CSV, diff customer information like first name, last name, email address to CSV easily at one query, without my browser/WAMP getting haulted.

Earlist reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by-pass PHP, in mysql command line, do

```
select first_name, last_name, email 
from your_table
into outfile 'C:\customer.csv';
/* you can apply all sort of filtering, string function etc .. */
```

Of course, you still call the above query using PHP (the above is clean-cut)

The generated csv is using tab delimiter.

Comment: for this one, I need to have MySQL command line access, right ? what if i don't have it?

Comment: If you do not have the access, you can use PHP to call the above query, **make sure PHP has the write access to C:\ or you can select other location the PHP+apache has the right to write**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your records are stored in MYSQL, and you've written a script in PHP that queries that db? 
The quickanddirty method for a one-time would be to execute your query in the mysql-client.

There should be a 'mysql' command in the WAMP dir I think (have used XAMP before, but it's similar?). At least your browser and Apache don't have anything to do with it anymore while using this method.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have it? The client is included in the WAMP installation and you should be able to use your password/username you use in php?